# Django Combine Two Tables Through a Third

Tags: django, django-models

If I have these 3 models

```
from django.db import models


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ModelC(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

What is the best way to get all of my `ModelA`'s and their associated `ModelB.property`'s? I can't figure out a good way to do it without a raw query.

Ideally I'd be able to transform it into:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    }
    ....
]
```

Comment: property is a reserved word in python - I would avoid using that as a django model field name (or variable) anywhere

Comment: It was clearly a mock example..

Answer (score 1):

Use `related_name` on the ForeignKeys

```
from django.db import models


class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    property = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ModelC(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name="theas")
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, related_name="thebs")
```

To get all ModelB instances that relate to an instance of ModelA

```
a_inst = ModelA.objects.get(foo=bar)
ModelB.objects.filter(thebs__a=a_inst)
```

Comment: Yes I understand that method, but I was hoping for a more efficient one. If I have to get a lot of ModelA's this is a lot of DB calls. I can do it in a single query with a few JOIN's, but I can't figure out how to do that in Django. It could be that the joins are actually slower, I don't know, I haven't benchmarked yet.

Comment: You have a clear manytomany relationship here. You are missing the manytomanyfield in either modela or modelb using modelc as a through table. If you set the correct reverse names then you could call it as modela.bs.all() from anywhere.